# Two Phase Commit on Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

So I was reading about this two phase commit:
http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/#performing-two-phase-commits

AFAIK, Couchbase operation is atomic.
Article explains when performing two phase commit I should create a **Trans:1** document, which contains the state of the Transaction progress.
1) First is start at **Init** state.

2) When Transaction start begin process, I should switch **Trans:1**'s state to **pend**.
*By switching to **pend** state, we can prevent other process pickup the same transaction.*

3) Then update the target document's content (in example is **dipti** and **karen**) to include a **trans** the same time.
*If anything fail during the update on either document, we can do a rollback, by checking the **trans:1** document's state is equals to **pend** *

So here is my questions:

a) Since Couchbase operation is atomic, if there is multiple processes try to come pickup the transaction **trans:1**, there is chance say **process A** got **trans:1's state = init**, before process A update **trans:1's state = pend**, **process B** may also got the same result **trans:1's state = init** and try to perform the update.

b) Same reason, when a process updated **trans::1** state to **pend**, update **dipti** and **karen**.  Because operation is atomic, they cannot really update the same time, only can be update one after another.
Then how can we prevent other process not getting/updating the value of **dipti** and **karen**?  Because their values is not completely updated.

c) Couchbase is not versioning like Couchdb, how do we do rollback actually?

d) What is the point of keeping **trans:1** and set to **state:done**?  Why not just delete the whole document when we know is done?

e) Last question, actually how should I make the transaction document being pickup? I mean like should I run a service that will constantly checking all the Transition document in Linux or something?  Running everytime when machine got rebooted?

(The example and codes there using cas() method, I have no idea what is the equivalent in PHP SDK, I imagine is means get()? )

Currently my approach is:
When **trans:1** is **state:init** the process will **getAndLock** all necessary documents (**dipti** and **karen**) and create copy of each of the documents (**trans:1::dipti** etc)
When **trans:1** is **state:pend** the process will update each document with **state:Processed**, so I know which documents got updated and need to rollback (from the copy of documents) if any failure.
And rollback will remove all copy documents and as well as the **trans:1**.

But it still doesn't prevent other process able to get **dipti** and **karen** while both is being updating.  (i.e.  Get total of **amount** of all people).

Comment: The point you are missing here is CAS, which stands for "Compare and Swap", is being used to ensure that no other request has modified the values. You can read more about it here: http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/retrieve-by-cas.html

Comment: @jeffrymorris Yes, their example is also using CAS and I have read about it. Actually that's my another question: Using PHP SDK, the query's response does contains the CAS value, but I don't see any method related to CAS in documentation....http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-php-client-2.0.7/

Comment: Btw, is called Check-and-Set in Couchbase: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/#check-and-set-cas