# How can I make sure that data is persisted to disk?

Tags: node.js, couchbase

while developing my project I encountered some problems. Firstly, how can I make sure that after making sub-document mutations the data is persisted to disk? For example, when I want to insert/upsert/replace the whole document I just do:

```
bucket.insert('key', 'value', { persist_to: 1 }, err => {
    // callback
});
```

but in the documentation I cannot find where should I put persist options in mutation queries. Currently the code I'm using:

```
bucket.mutateIn('key').counter('balance', -100).execute(err => {
    // callback
});
```

The next question is: how about n1ql queries? Are they able to callback only when the data is persisted to disk?

Comment: What is the reason you want the data to persist to disk? I don't know any good reason for that in a distributed database. That is the reason those have replicas.

Comment: I'm building a project that will have a large visitors traffic. Each user will have a balance and will be able to withdraw money. So I am trying to secure the application as much as possible.

Comment: but - large traffic means you want less latency = you do not want to force to persist to disk (it will get there eventually) . the fact that a document isn't persisted to disk doesn't mean you can't get the latest version of it.
Have you read this page? https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/durability.html

Comment: I won't use persisting to disk in all queries, just in that one when user requests withdrawal and balance must be reduced.

Comment: it is the wrong operation to use. you should use two phase commit with CAS, persisting to disk will not make anything safer here.

Comment: Could you give any article or tut about it? Because I cannot realise how it should look from the code side :)

Comment: try this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374201/two-phase-commit-on-couchbase

Comment: Btw about the persisting data to disk. Lets imagine, the user requests withdrawal, then after getting a successful callback the system sends a specified amount of bitcoins to the user's btc address, but immediately after it the server reboots unexpectedly and the data was only kept in RAM and not persisted to disk. After server reboots, the user has the same balance as he had before. I know that it is a very very rare case, but I want to make sure the website runs smoothly and we won't lose any money.

Comment: You should use replicas (assuming you have multi-node cluster) and use the replicate-to attribute.

Comment: Yes, but then how can I use replicate_to/persist_to properties in sub-document and n1ql queries?

Comment: you don't use it in N1QL it doesn't exist, it works a bit differently. with subdoc API- it is just like the normal CRUD K/V operations. BTW in your example you've used the non-subdoc api (regular one)

Comment: Yeah, I have read the documentation and found how to do it in non-subdoc queries http://prntscr.com/g35cb6 , but after doing some research in subdoc api documentation, I haven't found any solution how can I do it when retrieving/updating only a certain part of the document.

Comment: Updating a document via sub-doc api, is internally the same as updating a new document - it just sends less data to the server.  can you Elaborate with some code (edit your question).

Comment: Updated the question.